# HMAC vs BCrypt for Api Key encruption

Tags: api, security, encryption, api-key, password-encryption

I am designing an Api for a client and trying to keep it very basic. Instead of using an external library for the first iteration, we will be setting up an Api Key and allowing users to hit the endpoint with the key and their user id. The endpoint contains an ability that I want to keep hidden from vulnerable attacks, therefore I am thinking of treating the user id and Api key as a username/password for authentication. The key will be encrypted and stored in the database and when the user sends the headers over they will send the user id and api key over to be verified against. That all leads to the question below:

Is BCrypt too heavy of an encryption to authenticate an api endpoint against?

Comment: IMO If you're hashing the API key server-side, then HMAC is better because it's faster and the server's time is important.

Comment: @MichaelM. Thanks! I did some load testing and decided to go with HMAC